# Simple example of ViewPager without tabs

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment

I got a xml layout for main activity with some buttons on top of the screens. Below them is placed ViewPager:
`<ViewPager android:id="@+id/viewpager">`

I also got two fragments in mainactivity.class, each with it's own layout:
 `frag1 = new Fragment1(); frag2 = new Fragment2();` and `viewpager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);`

Now whats the simplest way to add these two fragments to ViewPager (but without using ActionBar TABS)? I also need to run some code according to which fragment is selected by user, for example make Toast with text "Fragment 2 is selected" when swiped to frag2.

---

Ok, now I have extended FragmentPagerAdapter: `Public class frAdapter extend FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {  ...  }`

What I'm supposed to do in getItem() method to add these fragments to viewpager?

Comment: what you mean by `actionbar tabs`?

Comment: i mean this: http://tihelp.me/wp/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/ActionBarNavigationTabs.png

Comment: I see, but actually I don't see any strong connections between the two components. You can use the view pager without the actionbar tab

Comment: android docs have an article http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html#horizontal-paging, see "Implement Swipe Views" section. Goal is to create FragmentPagerAdapter subclass